# git command line option to accept default commit message

Tags: git

Normally when making a git commit I use `git commit -m "message"`. However, in some cases git prepopulates a commit message, such as after resolving a conflict during a merge. Is there a way that I can specify via the command line that I would like to accept this default commit message, without opening an editor?

Answer (score 5):

`git commit --no-edit`

Works if, for example, you merged (with -m) but there were conflicts that had to be taken care of. Probably works on other cases as well.